# Measure performance of Silverlight / Moonlight applications

Tags: silverlight, performance, moonlight

I'm interested in high level performance measurement of Silverlight especially in comparison to Moonlight. I've browsed around and came up with some tools ([SilverliightSpy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/) among others) but there has to be other tools or ways to do this.

The high level questions I'd like to investigate are

- How does moonlight and silverlight compare wrt performance
- How should I design my app to get best performance (on SL, ML or both)

The performance characteristics I'm interested in are

- How does my test app utilize the CPU (rough comparison) - i.e. does it off load work to the GPU
- Rendering time. Not only FPS but also latency - "if I modify some visual element's properties..."

  - "...how long before they get updated on the screen"
  - "...how much is the CPU utilized during that time"

Any suggestions? It would be nice to be able to do this in-app, so that I can just run the app on Silverlight and then on Moonlight and compare its output. A cross platform profiler would also work though.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has answered yet I figured I could post my own findings since asking the question. I still haven't figured out how to measure how much time it took from modifying a visual's appearance until it has been drawn on screen.

To calculate CPU utilization inside your app you can use the [Analytics class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.analytics%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). To calculate the framerate, just hook in to the static [rendering event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) of the CompositionTarget class.

```
private DispatcherTimer fpsTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
private DateTime lastFpsUpdate;
private Analytics analyzer = new System.Windows.Analytics();
private int frameCount;

public MyClass()
{
    fpsTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    fpsTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(fpsTimer_Tick);
    fpsTimer.Start();
    lastFpsUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(CompositionTarget_Rendering);
}

// Called every second
void fpsTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double framerate = 0;
    framerate = frameCount / (DateTime.Now - lastFpsUpdate).TotalSeconds;
    c_statusMessage.Text = String.Format("Framerate: {0:0} fps, CPU utilization: {1:0.0}%", framerate, analyzer.AverageProcessLoad);
    lastFpsUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    frameCount = 0;
}

// Called by the framework on every frame
void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frameCount++;
}
```